# AttributeError when using while loop for dataframes columns

Tags: python, pandas, attributeerror

I was trying to solve an issue regarding deleting the last column of a dataframe until a certain column-length criteria is met, so I tried working on a very basic example before applying it to real problem but I am meeting this error I'm not too sure solve:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
a = {'ear':[1,3,32,2],'aear':[53,4,3,22],'was':[23,3,2,4]}
df = pd.DataFrame(a)
print(df.columns)
print(len(df.columns))
while len(df.columns) > 1: 
    df = df.drop(df.columns[len(df.columns)-1], axis=1, inplace=True)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
was
3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Celius.Stingher\Desktop\PYTHON\soo.py", line 7, in <module>
    while len(df.columns) > 1:
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'columns'
```

Could anyone please explain the source of the issue, because `len(df.columns)` is indeed resulting in 3, but using it in the while loop yields the error. Thanks a lot

Comment: Remove "inplace=True", because it returns None

Comment: @J.K: correct, but I'd rather remove the assignment instead of the `inplace`. Especially if the dataframe is large. Because removing it would cause unnecessary copy operations.

Comment: @jottbe, Yes remove the assignment will also solve the case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is because you use `inplace=True`.
If you use `inplace=True`, `drop` returns `None` and you assign that to the df-variable again.

So the following code should do, what you want:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
a = {'ear':[1,3,32,2],'aear':[53,4,3,22],'was':[23,3,2,4]}
df = pd.DataFrame(a)
print(df.columns)
print(len(df.columns))
while len(df.columns) > 1: 
    df.drop(df.columns[len(df.columns)-1], axis=1, inplace=True)
print(df)
```

Comment: Yes, it does work and thanks for the explination, will accept once the time is done.

Answer (score 1):

Because once you drop all columns - the dataframe becomes None too :)
After your code, before `print(df)` (last line):

```py
>>> df
>>> type(df)
<class 'NoneType'>
```

Comment: That's not true. If you drop the last column, the dataframe still is a dataframe, but with no column. You can try that.

Comment: Well, it's functional dataframe - but it's somehow read as None i.e. you can add columns and make it work, but you cannot do everything as with the non-empty df.

Comment: Yes, that's right. An empty dataframe isn't much fun. But it's not read as `None`. df just contains `None`, because `drop(inplace=True` never returns anything else than `None`. No matter how many columns the dataframe contains. I guess it is the same philosopy as the `sort` method in `list`etc. They also return `None` to make clear, the receiver is stored and not a copy of it.